# Issue in cordova background mode plugin

Tags: cordova-plugins

I am using the cordova background mode plugin for executing a service in background. It works fine until the app is minimized but once the app is removed from task bar or is completely closed, the service stops which shouldn't happen.
The service should run even if the app is closed.

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: can you provide code and link of the plugin you are using ?

Comment: Below is the code i m using and plugin link is https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Answer (score 0):

This is the following code I am using

```
     cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({
            title:  'Osprey',
            ticker: '',
            text:   'App is running in background!!!'
        });
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function() {
          cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
              if (enabled) {
                var marker;

                var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("my.db"); //mobile
                //var db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'auto', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
                //$cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Location;"); //drop a table
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Location (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE, date NUMERIC)");
                var options = {timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: false};

                $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){
                  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                  lat = position.coords.latitude;
                  long = position.coords.longitude;
                  var mapOptions = {
                    center: latLng,
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                  };

                  $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                  $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+long+'&sensor=true').
                    then(function(data){ 
                      console.log(data);
                      $scope.address='Your current location is : ' +data.data.results[0].formatted_address;
                  });
                  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function(){

                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: $scope.map,
                      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                      position: latLng,
                      draggable: true
                  }); 

                 var watchOptions = {maximumAge: 10000, timeout: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
                 //var watchOptions = {frequency : 1000,timeout : 3000,enableHighAccuracy: false };
                 var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);

                 watch.then(
                    null,

                    function(err) {
                       console.log(err.message);
                    },

                    function(position) {
                       //start fetch tracking status
                      var data = {};
                      data.companyId = $window.localStorage['companyId'];
                      data.apiKey = $window.localStorage['apiKey'];
                      $http({
                         method: 'POST',
                         url: "http://192.241.86.4/api/fetch-tracking-status",
                         crossDomain:true,
                         data: data
                          }).success(function (response) {
                            var j = response.length - 1;
                            if (response[0].startTime === null || response[j].endTime === null) {
                              $cordovaToast
                                .show('No Tracking For Now!!!', 'long', 'center')
                                .then(function(success) {
                                  console.log('success');
                                }, function (error) {
                                  console.log('error');
                                });
                            } else {
                               console.log('tracking');
                               var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
                               var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                               var new_marker_position = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                               marker.setPosition(new_marker_position);
                               var query = "INSERT INTO Location (latitude, longitude, date) VALUES (?,?,Date('now'))";
                                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]).then(function(res) {
                                    console.log("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
                                }, function (err) {
                                    console.log(err.message);
                                });
                            }
                        },function error(response) {
                          console.log("Error Saving Data");
                      });
                    }
                 );
                 //watch.clearWatch();

                  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: $scope.address
                  });

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                      infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                  });

                });

                if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
                  $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: "Internet Disconnected",
                    content: "The internet is disconnected on your device. Please Connect Internet"
                  })
                } else {
                  var location = {};
                  location.locations = [];
                  setInterval(function(){
                    var query = "select * from Location";
                    location.apiKey = $window.localStorage['apiKey'];
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query)
                    .then(
                        function(result) {
                            if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                              for (var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                                var object = {};
                                object.deviceId = $window.localStorage['imei'];
                                object.deviceName = $cordovaDevice.getModel();
                                object.phone = $window.localStorage['phone'];
                                object.companyId = $window.localStorage['companyId'];
                                object.createdDate = new Date().toUTCString();
                                object.batteryPercentage = $scope.showPercentage;
                                object.latitude = result.rows.item(i).latitude;
                                object.longitude = result.rows.item(i).longitude;
                                object.manual = "0";
                                location.locations.push(object);
                              }

                              $http({
                                 method: 'POST',
                                 url: "http://192.241.86.4/api/save-logs",
                                 crossDomain:true,
                                 data: location
                                  }).success(function (response) {
                                    $cordovaToast
                                      .show('Successfully Saved Location', 'long', 'center')
                                      .then(function(success) {
                                        console.log('success');
                                        var deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Location";
                                        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, deleteQuery).then(function(res) {
                                            console.log('deleted');
                                        }, function (err) {
                                            console.log(err.message);
                                        });
                                      }, function (error) {
                                        console.log('error');
                                      });
                                },function error(response) {
                                  console.log("Error Saving Data");
                                });
                            } else {
                              console.log('No places tracked');
                            }
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            console.log(error.message);
                        }
                      );
                  },20000);
                }

                }, function(error){
                  console.log("Could not get location");
                });
              } else {
                alert("Location is disabled");
                window.location.reload();
              }
          }, function(error) {
              console.log("The following error occurred: " + error);
          });
        }
```

Comment: You are making ajax calls in background mode. as plugin's document says "The system keeps all network connections open while in background, but does not deliver the data until the app resumes."

Comment: In that case when the app stays in taskbar it works fine but once it is closed from there, it gives an issue.

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible from JavaScript. you have to write Native Java code which does this job and keeps running as service in background.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ? 
I'm facing the same issue and couldn't find any answer

Comment: Modified the xisting plugin, wrote some native java code :)